# How can we cache ldap login credentials in mac using opendirectory

Tags: macos, openldap

In mac using Active Directory we can cache ldap login credentials by checking create mobile account at login. Is there any other way to do same thing in openldap. Please some one share information here

Comment: I feel many of us are looking forward for solution to this question. Even though we may not know proper solution.Please provide how you all are trying to solve this. So that we can work together to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please let me know if my answer resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Syammala and Stephen Rudolph,

**Per your question:** "Is there any other way to do the same thing in openldap"

You can indeed do this with OpenLDAP and [SSSD - Follow this documentation for installation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Enterprise/Authentication/sssd)

You'll want to set your config, like in the example to:

```
[domain/europe.example.com]
cache_credentials = true
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, that solution looks like it is actually providing Active Directory services in addition to OpenLDAP.

Comment: Yeah i too feel the same . Thanks for your answer @mbeacom